# Is maximizing $f = {X^T}{A^{ - 1}}X$ same as maximizing $f = {X^T}{\left( {A + {\sigma ^2}I} \right)^{ - 1}}X$ subject to the constraint $X^{T}X=1$

Tags: optimization

Where $X$ is an $N{\times}1$ vector, $A^{-1}$ is a $N{\times}N$ symmetric positive semi-definite matrix, and the elements of A=x[n] @x[-n],where A is the auto-correlation matrix, where @ means the convolution operator. $\sigma^2$ is a constant and $I$ is the  $N{\times}N$ identity matrix. 
What I tried to do is to argue that only the diagonal element of $A$ will change with an addition of a constant so that should not affect the maximum of the function itself.
As  a Note: In fact for my problem $A$ also depends on $X$ hence the function $f$ is a function of the vector $X$ and the matrix $A$ is also depends on the vector values in $X$.

Comment: $f$ depends on $X$?

Comment: Yes actually in fact A also depends on X hence the function f is a function of the vector X and the matrix A is also depends on the vector values in X.

Comment: You left out one important information: *How* does $A$ depend on $X$? Also, is $X\in\mathbb R^n$ arbitrary? I mean, can the values in $X$ be arbitrarily large in absolute value?

Comment: I added all the information needed thank you for pointing that out